# Does 'new Charts.newColumnChart().setDataSourceUrl' work in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having trouble getting the following code to work:

```
function doGet () {
  var colChart = new Charts.newColumnChart()
  .setDataSourceUrl('https://docs.google.com/a/1ins.us/spreadsheet/tq?&key=<mysecretkey>&tq=select%20N,%20S,%20count(A)%20Where%20A%20is%20not%20Null%20group%20by%20N,S')
  .build();
  var myapp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Report for problems');
  var mypanel = myapp.createVerticalPanel();
  mypanel.add(colChart);
  myapp.add(mypanel);
  return myapp;
}
```

I get this error:

> Method "newColumnChart" was invoked with [object Object] as "this"
>   value that can not be converted to type $Proxy715.

This occurs at the line containing `setDataSourceUrl()`. What is wrong there?

I've considered a number of possible problems, and have tried the following already:

- This is being used from a Google Apps for Business Account.
- I published the google spreadsheet.
- I tested the url in chrome browser and got JSON wrapped in

  ```
  google.visualization.Query.setResponse({
        "version":"0.6",
        "status":"ok",
        "sig":"983199261",
        "table":{"cols":[{......
  ```
- I tried to launch this from the GAS IDE by clicking on deploy as **web app**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of that new at the beginning. It's `Charts.newColumnChart()`, not `new Charts.newColumnChart()`.